# Can't force page size on print

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a table made in html/css that need to be printed on a 40.5cm x 21.5cm page, and I can't force, from css/html, to get printed on that size. I have this:

```
    html, body {
        width:40.5cm;
        height:21.5cm;
        margin:0cm;
        padding:0cm;
    }
    @page
    {
        width: 40.5cm;
        height: 21.5cm;
        margin:0;
    }
    @media print {
        html, body {
            width: 405mm;
            height: 215mm;
        }
    }
```

But every time I put print and "print to PDF", the PDF is created in "letter" page size. I tried to actually print it, and it appears on that size too. What I'm missing? I also tried @page size instead of @page width and height.

Comment: Im pretty sure this will be browser settings biased.  Unless youre controlling the PDF creation process (server side) I cant see how you can control the orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't override the print settings using css, the only solution for you it is create a pdf.
you can use https://parall.ax/products/jspdf and set the size using this:

open the website and change this: `var doc = new jsPDF();` for this:

```
new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [405, 215]);
```

and you can print your custom

[image]

Comment: I need to print several pages, and after another. In this solution I should create every pdf and then print it mannually? There's an option to send all files to the printer queue?

Comment: @DavidTG if you use some size like A4, A3... yes + google chrome can change the settings of the print if you use `@page {size: a4}`

Comment: I use a custom size (405x215mm) and I see the default size on Google Chrome and also can't add a custom size.

Comment: So what should I do for custom size?